# Cannot format a 64 GB Class 10 SanDisk card

Tags: ubuntu, sd-card, gparted

I have this card and it has suddenly gone read only. Windows and my phone can only read and cannot add or delete files from it. I am currently trying gparted to correct this card, but it is of no use. When I delete the partition and try to format it via gparted, it says this:

- libparted messages
  Can't have overlapping partitions.

Any ideas? I have personal pictures, bank passwords etc, I am really reluctant to send it to the service center. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything on the card you absolutely need? Y

Comment: Any chance it is fake? In the past cheap large USB drives had controlers that reported large sizes and even showed no errors when writing to non existent parts of the disk.

Comment: @rob: The card is legit, due to the personal data, I am finding myself to be a bit reluctant to send it to the service center. SanDisk cards are known for this kind of behaviour apparently, I had no idea. I just want to wipe the damn thing.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, I can copy the data, the last time I tried to, I just cannot delete from the sdcard.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for the nuclear option in this case - after backing up. I'm assuming you have a linux system - run the [shred command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shred_%28Unix%29) on `/dev/sdX` where sdx refers to the root device of the card. That will wipe clean all the partitions and leave you with a pristine, unpartitioned device. Then create a new fat32 partition the usual way.

If you also have a windows box or a OS X box, you may choose to format it with the [SD Association formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/) after that - its specifically designed for SD cards.